# DataTemplate.Triggers vs Style.Triggers

Tags: wpf, data-binding

In order to change ListBoxItem foreground base on condition, I can do via DataTemplate.Triggers:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    ...
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="Item1">
            <Setter Property="ListBoxItem.Foreground" Value="Blue" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Or, I can do inside Style.Triggers:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="Item1">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Questions:

I wonder what's the difference between these 2 approaches?

Is there any scene that I should use one over another?

What is each one best for?

If I apply both of them, which trigger happen first?

Answer (score 5):

In the example that you have, the style trigger would apply to all list box items whereas the data template trigger would apply to the list box item using the data template.

The good part of WPF is that there are multiple ways to achieve a single goal. For most of the questions that you have, you will have to play around with triggers to get an answer.

In general, style triggers are used to change the  style and "generally" will not interact with data (however, I have seen code in stackoverflow where its used both ways). If I were you, since you are modifying a background - I would use a style with a key.